# Develop C# console app that find all process that use DirectX

Tags: c#, .net, process, console-application, directx

I need to develop a small console application which searches through all windows processes if one is using windows DirectX.

Any suggestions? I searched for, but I haven't been able to find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, I needed to find out if a process uses a File I want to edit, it takes the Name of a File and shows the process that has it open maybe you can use it to solve your problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <RestartManager.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int __cdecl wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv)
{
 DWORD dwSession;
 WCHAR szSessionKey[CCH_RM_SESSION_KEY+1] = { 0 };
 DWORD dwError = RmStartSession(&dwSession, 0, szSessionKey);
 wprintf(L"RmStartSession returned %d\n", dwError);
 if (dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
   PCWSTR pszFile = argv[1];
   dwError = RmRegisterResources(dwSession, 1, &pszFile,
                                 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
   wprintf(L"RmRegisterResources(%ls) returned %d\n",
           pszFile, dwError);
  if (dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
   DWORD dwReason;
   UINT i;
   UINT nProcInfoNeeded;
   UINT nProcInfo = 10;
   RM_PROCESS_INFO rgpi[10];
   dwError = RmGetList(dwSession, &nProcInfoNeeded,
                       &nProcInfo, rgpi, &dwReason);
   wprintf(L"RmGetList returned %d\n", dwError);
   if (dwError == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"RmGetList returned %d infos (%d needed)\n",
            nProcInfo, nProcInfoNeeded);
    for (i = 0; i < nProcInfo; i++) {
     wprintf(L"%d.ApplicationType = %d\n", i,
                              rgpi[i].ApplicationType);
     wprintf(L"%d.strAppName = %ls\n", i,
                              rgpi[i].strAppName);
     wprintf(L"%d.Process.dwProcessId = %d\n", i,
                              rgpi[i].Process.dwProcessId);
     HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
                                   FALSE, rgpi[i].Process.dwProcessId);
     if (hProcess) {
      FILETIME ftCreate, ftExit, ftKernel, ftUser;
      if (GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreate, &ftExit,
                          &ftKernel, &ftUser) &&
          CompareFileTime(&rgpi[i].Process.ProcessStartTime,
                          &ftCreate) == 0) {
       WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];
       DWORD cch = MAX_PATH;
       if (QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hProcess, 0, sz, &cch) &&
           cch <= MAX_PATH) {
        wprintf(L"  = %ls\n", sz);
       }
      }
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  RmEndSession(dwSession);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MarkusDeibel mybe because it is not C#, I am not a free Coding Machine this is only supposed to be a first start for him. But you are free to code it in C# and post it!